# Screenshot (PIL)ImageGrab.grab / BitBlt on Win10 only return the Background?

Tags: python, windows-10, screenshot, python-imaging-library, bitblt

i have a big problem with windows 10, normaly i used PIL (Python) to get a nice and clean screenshot from inside a program.

but with windows 10 this does not work anymore, now i become only everything on the Desktop but my FullScreen Window is missing.

i also tryed to use:

```
BitBlt(screen_copy, 0, 0, width, height, screen, left, top, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT)
```

but the result is exactly the same :(

does anybody has any solution or idea what has changed in Win10?

thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that is really fast is the [MSS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mss/) module. It uses only the `ctypes` standard module, so it does not require any dependencies. It is OS independant, works with Windows 10 and its use is made easy:

```
from mss import mss

with mss() as sct:
    sct.shot()
```

And just find the `screenshot.png` file containing the screen shot of the first monitor. There are a lot of possibile customizations, you can play with `ScreenShot` objects and OpenCV/Numpy/PIL/etc..

Comment: Is it OK for you? If yes, could you accept the answer please?